# How to append to the final dimension?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, append, field

I load multiple structs from separate files and want to collect them in one struct of arrays. Since the struct has a lot of fields, I'm looping over its `fieldnames`, at the moment like this:

```
for fnc = fieldnames(result)'
  fn = fnc{:}
  results.(fn) = [results.(fn) result.(fn)];
end
```

This works fine for scalar fields, however some fields are vectors or matrices and should therefore be stored as matrices or 3rd rank tensors respectively. I can use some `if length` and `if ndims` to treat these cases individually, but

> is there a more general way to use the next higher dimension for appending?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append along the last dimension, you can use the commands [CAT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cat.html) and [NDIMS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndims.html):

```
%# find the number of dimensions
nd = ndims(results.(fn));
%# catenate along the last dimension
results.(fn) = cat(nd,results.(fn), newResult.(fn));
```

Note that building arrays by catenation can be fairly slow if there are lots of iterations, though in your case, pre-allocating will be somewhat involved, so I'd only do it if it's really necessary. Also, using variables `results` as well as `result` is setting yourself up for hard-to find bugs.

Comment: since for the first iteration, results (which I actually call r to lessen(?!) confusion) is not initialized, I use `nd = ndims(result.(fn))+1` instead. Works perfectly then, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution with which I'm not all too happy:

```
    % merge current result fields into results
    resFields = fieldnames(result);
    for jf = 1:numel(resFields)
        rf = resFields{jf};
        resf = result.(rf);
        nd = ndims(resf);
        rt = r.(rf);
        if nd==2 && min(size(result.(rf)))==1 % scalar or vector
            rt = [ rt; result.(rf) ];
        elseif nd == 2 % true matrix, so append to 3rd rank tensor
            rt(:,:,end+1) = result.(rf);
        elseif ndims(result.(rf)) == 3 % 3rd rank tensor, append to 4th rank tensor
            rt(:,:,:,end+1) = result.(rf);
        else
            warning(['Too many dimensions for result field ' rf ': ' num2str(ndims(result.(rf)))]);
            rt(end+1) = result.(rf);
        end;
        results.(rf) = rt;
        end;
    end;
```

I could of course manually extend this to any tensor rank up to a sensible degree, but this is very redundant and ugly, so I'd really appreciate a better looking solution that works in the general case as well.